# How can i drop packet in kernel after catched it by sock_raw in usermode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have use sock_raw get all ip packet from kernel.

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(protocol);
```

But packet still alive in kernel, how can i drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. When you receive the packet on a raw socket, the kernel has created a copy and delivered it to your receiving process. The packet will continue being processed in the meantime according to the usual semantics. It's likely this will have completed (i.e. whatever the stack would normally do with it will already be done) by the time your process receives it.

However, if the packet is not actually destined to your box (e.g. you're receiving it only because you have the network interface in promiscuous mode), or if there is no local process [or in-kernel component] interested in receiving it, the packet will just be discarded anyway.

If you simply wish to receive all packets that arrive on an interface without processing them, you can simply bring the interface up in promiscuous mode without giving it an IP address. Then packets will be delivered to your raw socket but will then be discarded by the stack.

Comment: What if I call setsockopt(fd , SOL_PACKET , PACKET_RX_RING , (void*)&req , sizeof(req)) to map the kernel buffer to the userspace?  Doing so will make the kernel completely not process the packets at all?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. The packet ring feature allows the kernel to transfer a copy of the packet to your process without incurring the overhead of a system call for each packet. However, the packet will still be processed in whatever way it would have been processed anyway. Furthermore, what you get *is a copy*; the actual kernel socket buffer memory is *not* mapped into userspace. There is a separate memory area allocated for the process to which the packet is copied.

Comment: I am a bit confused now as I read couple articles regarding zero copy.  Here is one from kernel.org: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt, it sounds like zero copy is possible with the ring buffer.

Comment: Yeah. I'm aware of that, but it's just not correct. There are networking technologies that are true zero copy. But none (AFAIK) are included in the mainstream kernel. See netmap and PF_RING (not the same as PACKET_RX_RING!). There are several others as well. Here's a recent article discussing them: https://blog.cloudflare.com/kernel-bypass/

Comment: Very interesting article. Now, I am curious what the kernel does to the UDP packets that are also copied to PACKET_RX_RING.  You mentioned that the kernel will process them in the usual semantics but what if the packets are destined only to the sniffed application not any other application on the machine? Kernel will read them, do checksum, queue up etc, and then drop (due to buffer full?)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean: the "sniffed application" is the one that is receiving packets via packet_mmap? In order for packets to be "destined" for it, the process would need to have a datagram socket listening on the destination port. This is a completely different mechanism that is orthogonal to packet_mmap (packet_mmap is specifically for sniffing raw packets). If there is no process listening on that port, the packets will be dropped (immediately after they're copied to the mmap queue). If there is a listener, then yes, they would be queued up to the buffering limits.

Comment: yea, the sniffing application is the one receiving packets via packet_mmap.  Thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but others might find this answer useful.

Depends on the usecase, but you can actually drop ingress packets after you get them from AF_PACKET SOCK_RAW. To do that, put an ingress qdisc where we have drop action. Example:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: matchall action drop
```

Explaination: this works, because the AF_PACKET sniff the packet's copy from the per-device tap, which is a little bit earlier than the ingress qdisc in the kernel network stack's packet processing pipeline. That way you can implement a simple userspace switch.